# sh: 1: concurrent: not found while npm start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to setup angular2 on my local machine, I installed node and npm, after installing npm when I do 'npm start' I am getting below error

```
root@sameer-Vostro-2520:/home/sameer/angular2/angular-2-beta-boilerplate# npm start

> angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 start /home/sameer/angular2/angular-2-beta-boilerplate
> concurrent "npm run gulp" "npm run lite" 

sh: 1: concurrent: not found
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can we fix this?

installed concurrent but again same error

```
concurrently@2.2.0 /root/.node/lib/node_modules/concurrently
├── commander@2.6.0
├── bluebird@2.9.6
├── cross-spawn@0.2.9 (lru-cache@2.7.3)
├── moment@2.14.1
├── rx@2.3.24
├── lodash@4.13.1
└── chalk@0.5.1 (supports-color@0.2.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@1.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)



> angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 start /home/sameer/angular2/angular-2-beta-boilerplate
> concurrent "npm run gulp" "npm run lite" 

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't installed concurrent. Try installing it globally first. `npm install -g concurrently`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got fixed after installing nodejs-legacy

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Answer (score 2):

First run `yarn` and then `npm start` again

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer

Answer (score -1):

**Someone who is having difficult running command in your package json file and getting error like**

```
[0] /bin/sh: xxx: command not found
[1] /bin/sh: xxx: command not found
```

**Solution -**
Note You are running npm commands via npm so your command should use

npm:

**Example -**
if you got, following npm command
start, build, lint

You will have concurrently command like this

```
"scripts: {
  "start": "ng start",
  "build": "ng build",
  "lint": "ng lint"
  "run:all": "concurrently npm:start npm:build npm:lint"
}
```

See in above script usage of npm: