# NPM install error .log

Tags: npm-install

I've tried with everything, typings -g, cache clean, update, sudo. Someone please can help me? I few days ago this was working.

This is what I've tried:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343657/sh-1-concurrent-not-found-while-npm-start

Comment: Nope, it isn't the same :(